# Confusion over current in an extreme long wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

Imagine we have a circuit with an extremely long wire (like some light years). Usually, the electric field from the battery would cause electrons in the wire to move thus creating a magnetic field and the energy would be transported through the Poynting vector from EM waves. But when the wire is too long, the battery’s electric field should be too weak, to be equally strong at every point like we always assume in DC circuits. At the lightbulb thousands of lightyears away, the electron should have no drift velocity cause there is almost zero electric field.

Is that correct?

Comment: We don't assume the battery's electric field is equally strong at every point, and in fact it's not. What we assume in a DC circuit is that any two points connected by an (ideal) conductor are at the same potential.

Comment: @JohnDoty you are just wrong. You cannot assume idealness because the wires are so long as to require explicit consideration. Ohm's law must be considered for the wires themselves.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Sure, for a real wire you must account for resistance. But the electric field of the battery doesn't come in. It's just Ohm's law.

Comment: @JohnDoty Ohm's Law asserts the relationship between the current density and the electric field. There must be an electric field in the wire.

Comment: Anyway, OP, what you are considering is just that the long wire has more resistance and thus the electric field becomes smaller. There is no limit for how small the electric field and the current density can be; the drift velocity can be as small as it needs to be. Things will just work.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Except the OP talks of Poynting flux, which is connected to the electric field *perpendicular* to the wire. And, in real life, the field in a practical circuit is mostly not in the wire direction.

Comment: @JohnDoty Poynting flux is the correct computation and interpretation. Yours, however, is wrong, even though there are some correct and interesting parts. It is simply necessary to obey Ohm's law inside the wire for everything to be correct.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Nothing I said is wrong, but you and I are interpreting an unrealistic question differently.

Answer (score 0):

An infinitely long wire is an idealization. You can imagine a battery in a really long wire working. But there is no place to put a battery in an infinitely long wire. It isn't a realistic situation.

But it is useful to think about. If you have a current flowing in an infinitely long wire, calculating the magnetic field is easy. And that is the purpose - creating easy situations to calculate things or think about symmetry. You can learn things from it.

Don't get hung up on how it isn't realistic. A really long wire is pretty close to the same thing. You wouldn't be able to measure the difference in magnetic field. So it is close to a real situation.